# Differences between jQuery.data() and .data()?

Tags: javascript, jquery

So, i was reading the *jquery* documentation and i couldn't identify the differences between the functions `jQuery.data()` and `.data()`. What are the main difference between those functions?

Here is the link to documentation: [Doc jquery](https://api.jquery.com/category/data/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latter is just a more convenient syntax for the former: `$.(domElement, 'key')` and `$('selector').data('key')` do the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

From the link you provided - it would appear it is simply just an older way of calling the same functionality in a more 'vanilla javascript' way...but it would appear there is one actual difference listed.

> Note: This is a low-level method; a more convenient .data() is also
>   available.
>
> Regarding HTML5 data-* attributes: This low-level method does NOT
>   retrieve the data-* attributes unless the more convenient .data()
>   method has already retrieved them.