# Why do jQuery.data and .data() behave differently and access different data?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I used to think that [jQuery.data](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/) and [.data()](https://api.jquery.com/data/) use the same data but are just 2 ways to access this data. After some tests I found out, that this isn't the case.

data() gets data from data-attributes from the DOM and attaches new or changed data to the DOM-Element while not being displayed in the DOM itself.

jQuery.data behaves pretty similar but don't get the data from the data-attribute.

And both methods don't access the same attached data to the DOM-Element.

```
var newDiv = $("#newDiv");
var temp = newDiv.data("test");
console.log(temp); //is default
console.log(newDiv.data("test")); //also default
console.log($.data(newDiv, "test")); //undefined

//change jQueryElement.data
newDiv.data("test", "ElementChange");
console.log(newDiv.data("test")); //now ElementChange

//get and change jQuery.data
console.log($.data(newDiv, "test")); //still undefined
$.data(newDiv, "test", "directChange");
console.log($.data(newDiv, "test")); //now directChange

console.log(newDiv.data("test")); //still ElementChange
```

I made a jsfiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/mgpfw2rr/

Now I wonder why there are 2 methods with only little differences in their initiation-data? At another question at stackoverflow the answer was, that both do the same thing ([Differences between jQuery.data() and .data()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35732152/differences-between-jquery-data-and-data)) which doesn't seem to be correct or?

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: The docs you linked to seem to contain all the information you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mention by Andreas it even stands in the documentation that jQuery.data doesn't retrieve the data and that .data() is just a new more comfortable method.

Thanks, I thought there would be "more" and didn't notice this at the documentation!